# How to set first option's value of Select Box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select list:

```
<select id='myList'> 
        <option value="">zero</option> 
        <option value="1">one</option> 
        <option value="2">two</option> 
        <option value="3">three</option> 
</select>
```

How can i set the value of option value to = 0 using jQuery?

I tried `$("#myList > option").attr("value", "0");`

But this changed them all,

I also tried `$("#myList:first-child").attr("value", "0");` but this breaks the select box.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#myList > option:first").attr("value", 0);
```

use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to filter

you could also,

```
$("#myList :first-child").attr("value", 0); // watch out for the space in the selector
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#myList option[value='']").attr("value", "0");
```